# Searching for java usort library

Tags: java, usort

Is there any equalent for PHP's `usort` function in Java? Some library or anything. Thanks.

I guess it could be programmable through some iterfaces, so if you know about something i'd be glad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`java.util.Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29).
You'd have to implement the Comparator, which would be equivalent to implementing the function you pass to PHP's `usort`.

A silly example of an implementation of the comparator (for Strings):

```
public class MySillyExampleClass implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {      
        return s1.length()-s2.length();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use either [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) or [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). You only need to implement your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There isn't such a tool.

What you can do is sort an List of elements with Collection.sort() and a custom Comparator.

What I would do is transform the values so that a natrual sort is correct. After the sort transform the values back. If you have to you can use a larger type e.g. `int[]` => `long[]` where the top bits have the transformed sortable value and the lower bits have the original => `int[]` by taking the lower bits.